# from south.db import db replaced by what in django 1.7+?

Tags: django, django-south, django-1.7

I'm amending someone else's code to run with django 1.8 and I wonder if there is a direct replacement for the line

```
 from south.db import db
```

uses include:

```
if db.backend_name == "postgres":
    db.start_transaction()
    db.execute_many(commands.PG_DISABLE_TRIGGERS)
    db.commit_transaction()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, the replacements are:

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db import transaction
```

Usages:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.vendor
u'postgresql'
```

And:

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db import transaction

cursor = connection.cursor() 
with transaction.atomic():
    cursor.executemany(commands.PG_DISABLE_TRIGGERS)
```